# Cannot insert data from Python List into SQL

Tags: python, sql, instagram

I get this error when I run the script bellow, I am able to connect to Instagram API and to print nr of followers: 
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

```python
followers = str(followers)
followersdata = [followers]



conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='XXX',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='InstagramStore')

cursor = conn.cursor()

q = """INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers (followers) VALUES (%s)"""

cursor.executemany(q, followersdata)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert into multiple values in one execute with
giving a list into execute command.
The problem is in query.

First you should format your query via

```
query = """INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers {0} VALUES ({1})""".format(followers, values)
```

Then you should give your values in a list

```
cursor.execute(query, list)
```

Comment: Hi Melikesahin, thanks, you're correct. The only thing that I had to change is executemany for execute as you suggested.

Comment: I usually use this method instead of executemany , advice you too, glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have your query incorrectly formatted.
I didnt know what the second `%s` stood for in your query, so I just used the variable `values` to hold its place.

It should look more like:

**Python <2.6**

```
q = """INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers (%s) VALUES (%s)""" (followers, values)
```

**Python >2.6**

```
q = """INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers {0} VALUES {1}""".format(followers, values)
```

**Python >3.6**

```
q = f"""INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers {followers} VALUES {values}"""
```

Comment: Hi Jack, 
My Python version is Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda, Inc.;
When I changed the script to q = """INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers {0} VALUES {1}""".format(followers, followersdata) 
I still got the same error message.  Am I still missing something?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @pepperjohn can you check `print type(followersdata)` and also please provide a full traceback for the error you described in the question

Comment: Sure! If I print the type it's a list. As per the full error, here it is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instagram_followers_dry.py", line 37, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(q, followersdata)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 370, in executemany
    "Failed executing the operation; {0}".format(err))
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

Comment: Hi @JackWalsh, 
I actually tried this now instead: 
q = """INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers {0} VALUES {1}""".format(followers, followersdata)
cursor.execute(q)

Now I get this error: ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '185 VALUES ['185']' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert the list to json and write the json into the table.

```
INSERT INTO InstagramFollowers(followers) VALUES(json.dumps(followersdata))
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi @masonCOD, 
If I use that function I get this error: FUNCTION json.dumps does not exist

Comment: @pepperjohn have you imported json?